# Can SpringFox generate Swagger Spec using Interface

Tags: springfox

I have an interface

```
public interface WebExportable {
      @RequestMapping("/export")
      Object export();
}
```

Does SpringFox support generating Swagger Spec using only the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Springfox does support annotations on interfaces. However not all of them seem to traverse to super classes for resolution. I have tryed to outsource swagger annotations to interfaces and then let the `Controller` classes implement them. I have found out that nearly all of them will get resolved by Springfox but not the `@ApiParam` `@PathVariable` combination.

There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1575) on GitHub.

Comment: That was useful to know.  However my ask was actually to know if I can use interfaces as input to Spring Fox to generate the spec?  The reason is that I have centralized all the interfaces in a java module and wanted to know if I could use only these for SpringFox.  I am not talking about the controller classes that implement the interfaces

Comment: Yes you can. I am using Springfox in a separate maven module which contains only interfaces (no controllers).